# Приложение в виде браузера без адресной строки

Tags: android, java

Есть вот такая задачка: нужно создать приложение, которое по сути является браузером без адресной строки. При запуске пользователь попадает на определенную страницу. И как сделать так, чтобы при клике на определенный номер на этой странице в виде ссылки производился вызов на этот номер? Я новичек, не будьте снобами) Помогите. С JAVA не знаком, но имею опыт на .NET C#.

Comment: Тега "Andorid" вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы показывать страницу нужен WebView. Для отслеживания кликов по ссылкам и выполнения дополнительных действий можно слушать onTouch и в обработчике определять, по чему был произведен клик с помощью HitTestResult (PHONE_TYPE), и если это номер телефона, то сохранять его

```
HitTestResult htr = wv.getHitTestResult();

if (htr.getType() == PHONE_TYPE) {
    String phone = htr.getExtra();
}
```

А для выполнения звонка использовать соответствующий Intent

```
Intent ac = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

ac.setData(Uri.parse(phone));
startActivity(ac);
```